# GL ES 2.0 Failing to create opengl objects

Tags: android, opengl-es

Basically I've just delved into some Android and OpenGL ES 2.0 programming and hit a bit of a problem.

My code compiles fine and it runs but the opengl functions don't seem to be working.

```
GLES20.createShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER); 
GLES20.glCreateProgram();
```

all will return 0.

Similarly this:

```
int posHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mShader.getProgramId(), "vPosition");
```

will return -1 and so on.

How I create my activity:

```
// Activity

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mSurfaceView = new GLESSurfaceView(this);

    final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final ConfigurationInfo configInfo = activityManager.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
    final boolean supports_gles2 = configInfo.reqGlEsVersion >= 0x20000;

    if (supports_gles2)
    {
        mSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mSurfaceView.setRenderer(new GLESRenderer());
    }
    else
    {
        //Log.e("", "Doesn't support GLES 2.0");
    }

    setContentView(mSurfaceView);
}
```

I've got this in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

I think that should be it to allow GLES 2.0 functions to work right? I can give more code if needed but its basically just shader setup, creating vertex buffers and then rendering a basic shape.

Cheers guys

EDIT: I should add that GLES20.glGetError() returns GL_NO_ERROR flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found out what I was doing wrong. I was creating my shaders and geometry in constructor for my Renderer class. All I did was move it to the onSurfaceCreated() and it was all good.

Answer (score 0):

On Android, all OpenGL ES calls must execute from the same thread.  If you use GLSurfaceView, it takes care of the threading for you.  This article explains in detail:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-1